# Learning Haskell and want to do a reverse polish notation evaluator

Tags: haskell

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
step [] "" = []
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x*y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (x - y):ys
step xs numString = read numString::[Int]
```

I want to print in such as step [4,3,5] "+" and within "" it can also extract the integer using read function. For example "3,4" however I will get

```
*Main> step [3,4,5,6,7,8,9] "+,3"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Hoping that I can, later on, apply it in the following rpn function with foldl function!

```
rpn:: [String]->Int
```

Can anyone tell me why or fix the error, please!

Comment: AFAICT, you're basically going `read "+,3"`. What do you expect that expression to do? What *does* it do?

Comment: @MarkSeemann  I want it to be able to extract integers from the strings for further use in my rpn

Comment: `read` parses a *string* into some other data type. `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` already *is* a value of another data type; it's not clear what you want `read` to do.

Comment: @chepner so as I said I hope to apply my step function into rpn:: [String]->Int, therefore I will need the Int in the String, sorry I am a newbie to Haskell. Thank you for giving me the concept behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think carefully about what `step` is supposed to do.  I suspect what you (eventually) want is to take an RPN string like:

```
"1 2 + 6 *"
```

break it into single-word tokens:

```
["1", "2", "+", "6", "*"]
```

and then apply those tokens one-by-one using `step` to a stack.

So, `step` should takes an initial stack and a **SINGLE** token, and return the resulting stack.  For example, after `"1"` and `"2"` have been processed and the stack looks like `[2,1]`, you'd like to use `step` to apply the `"+"` token like so:

```
> step [2,1] "+"
[3]
```

The definitions for the operators look fine:

```
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x*y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (x - y):ys
```

except you might want to think about the order of `x` and `y` for the subtraction operator.  Most people would expect `"10 5 -"` to give result 5, but because pushing `10` and `5` onto the stack will give a stack of `[5,10`], your implementation of `"-"` will calculate `5 - 10` instead of `10 - 5`.  Anyway, you can worry about this later.

The problem is the other two definitions:

```
step [] "" = []
step xs numString = read numString::[Int]
```

The first one seems pointless.  It says that, in the special case that the original stack is empty, processing an empty token will leave it empty.  When would you process an empty token?  What's supposed to happen if you process an empty token and the stack *isn't* empty?  I think you're trying to build the initial state of the stack into the `step` function, but that's going to be the responsibility of `foldl` function, so `step` shouldn't be dealing with that.  Just get rid of it.

The `numString` definition is wrong.  It says that, if the previous arithmetic operators don't match, we're going to throw away the old stack and read the current token as a new stack.  For this to work, the token would have to look like `"[1,2,3,4]"`, and it would replace the original stack.  When would you ever have a token that looked like this?  Why would you want to throw away the original stack?

Instead, you want to be able to handle a token consisting of a single number, like `"1"`.  The way to handle this will be to `read` it as a single integer and push it onto the existing stack:

```
step xs numString = read numString : xs
```

Here, because `read numString` is used in a context that expects an `Int` (because it's being added to the head of a list of `Int`s), it will read a single numeric token, like `"3"` or `"42"`.  As you can see, it pushes it onto the existing stack, which is exactly what you want it to do:

```
> step [1,2,3] "42"
[42,1,2,3]
```

Anyway, with the corrected definition:

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x*y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (x - y):ys
step xs numString = read numString : xs
```

you can now see how it would work processing the example above.  Here, I've started with an empty stack and then manually copied the stack forward as I apply each token using the `step` function:

```
> -- processing "1 2 + 6 *"...
> step [] "1"
[1]
> step [1] "2"
[2,1]
> step [2,1] "+"
[3]
> step [3] "6"
[6,3]
> step [6,3] "*"
[18]
```